# Updating database using dropdown without using a submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to update the table `status` value whenever I make a selection from the dropdown list.

The problem is I'm having a syntax error on my update query. I've read stuff about syntax error and I can't quite understand it. I think I'm gonna need a more specific help. Here's what I've done:

```
<?php

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $databasename = "companydb";

    try
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$databasename",$username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        if(isset($_POST["status"]))
        {
            $query = "UPDATE tickets SET status = '$status' WHERE id = $id";
            $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute(array('status' => $_POST["status"]));

            $count = $statement->rowCount();
            if($count > 0)
            {
                echo "Data Inserted Successfully..!";
            }
                else
            {
                echo "Data Insertion Failed";
            }
        }
            else
        {
            echo "unknown index: 'status'";
        }
    }

    catch(PDOException $error)
    {
        echo $error->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

And here's my table schema:

[image]

Comment: what's the error been throw?

Comment: @BitsPlease `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not performing prepared statements properly. You need to add the placeholder in the query and not the variables. The variables should be added in the `execute()` line.

```
$query = "UPDATE tickets SET `status` = :status WHERE `id` = :id";
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(array(':status' => $_POST["status"],':id' => $id));
```

Also FYI, `$id` is undefined.

Comment: Yes I know that, for now I was just trying to figure out the update query. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing this:

```
$query = "UPDATE tickets SET status = $status WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: I still get the same error, thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: Can you please try to post and check does static values gets updated? SET status = '1' and check?